# Can we integrate Firebase and react native app without a specific platform?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native

I start `react-native` by following expo cli [Expo cli Facebook Guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)

Then I want to integrate with firebase by following [the docs from invertase.io](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/quick-start/existing-project)

Seems like the docs only support a specific platform. Can I integrate react-native and firebase without specific platform? With Expo Cli we don't need to create android/ios folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is a document to integrate firebase to Expo.
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-firebase/

You can't use react-native-firebase wiht Expo, because react-native-firebase has native code.

Expo supports only js.

Use firebase of web.